# Why does UnZip extract the last concatenated ZIP?

Tags: linux, unix, unzip

I found the following behavior to be unexpected:

```
$ mkdir tmp && cd tmp/
$ for example in a b c ; do echo $example > $example.txt ; done
$ for file in `ls *` ; do zip $file.zip $file ; done
$ cat a.txt.zip b.txt.zip c.txt.zip > concatenated.zip
$ unzip concatenated.zip -d output
$ ls output/
c.txt                                     # unexpected
```

On the other hand, p7zip does this:

```
$ rm -r output/
$ 7z x concatenated.zip -ooutput/
$ ls output/
a.txt
```

Why does UnZip extract the last concatenated ZIP? Does it traverse backwards from EOF until it finds the PK file signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it traverse backwards from EOF until it finds the PK file signature?

Yes. Here is what `unzip` will do:

- look for the "end of central directory record" (EOCD) at the end of the zip file
- read the record and follow the "offset of start of central directory"
- read the central directory (it contains the list of every entries in the archive)
- read each entry and follow the "relative offset of local header"
- read the local header with the data and extract it

In you case, you will only find the last EOCD with a wrong offset (you prepended bytes). That's why `unzip` tells you:

```
warning [concatenated.zip]:  324 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
  (attempting to process anyway)
```

It finds the central directory of `c.txt.zip`, sees only one entry (`c.txt`), extracts only one file.

Given the structure of zip files, I would say it's the logical thing to do. Self extracting zip files use this: the file starts with a binary to extract itself and ends with the actual zip content (see `unzipsfx` and `zip -A`).

It looks like 7z will try from the end if the file **doesn't** start like a zip file:

```
# not a.txt.zip, but a.txt
$ cat a.txt b.txt.zip c.txt.zip > prepended.zip
# fix offset
$ zip -A prepended.zip

$ unzip -l prepended.zip 
Archive:  prepended.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        2  2016-11-22 20:29   c.txt
---------                     -------
        2                     1 file


$ 7z l prepended.zip 
[...]
Path = prepended.zip
Warning: The archive is open with offset
Type = zip
Physical Size = 326
Embedded Stub Size = 164

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2016-11-22 20:29:05 .....            2            2  c.txt
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2016-11-22 20:29:05                  2            2  1 files
```

Note `zip -A` to fix offsets:

> The -A option tells zip to adjust the entry offsets stored in the archive to take into account this "preamble" data.

I don't know what your are trying to achieve, but concatenating zip files may not be the easiest way (extracting them back will not be easy).